# Calling Service method from Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I am trying to call a method in my service from my activity which are bounded. However i keep getting the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void co.app.services.LocalService.methodOne()' on a null object reference
```

I am trying to call the `methodOne()`

Here is my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
LocalService mService;

private boolean mBounded = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //startService(intent);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        LocalService.MyBinder binder = (LocalService.MyBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBounded = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mService = null;
        mBounded = false;
    }
};

public void publishMain(View view){
    mService.methodOne();

}
```

Here is my service

```
    public class LocalService extends Service {
    private String TAG = "TestService";

    private IBinder myBinder = new MyBinder();

    public LocalService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBind done");

        return myBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return false;
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        public LocalService getService() {
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand done");


        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }



    public void methodOne() {
Log.i("method", "test");



    }
}
```

PublishMain is called from a button in activity_main layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Publish"
        android:onClick="publishMain"
        android:id="@+id/PublishSubmit"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where is the invocation statement for `methodOne` or `publishMain`  , please post the complete problematic code

Comment: the issue is , your services is not yet binded with your activity and you are trying to call it's function so try to put a toast inside `onServiceConnected` function to see when your service is ready plus use `mBounded ` flag variable

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, i managed to fix it by running the command startService(intent) directly before binding to it, it seemed to work by doing this.